# Intuition of $\left<f-a_0,f-a_0\right> =\left<f+a_0,f-a_0\right>$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, inner-products, periodic-functions

> Let be $\left<f,g\right>:=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)dx$, where $f$ and $g$ are $2\pi$-periodic and Riemann integrable functions, and $\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)$ a partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$.
>
> Then, we know that the Fourier coefficients $a_k$ of $f$ are defined by
> $$a_0:=\left<f,\cos(x\cdot 0)\right>\text{ and }a_k:= \left<f,\cos(x\cdot k)\right>.$$

---

After some tricky algebraic manipulations I have spotted that

$$\left<f-a_0,f-a_0\right> =\cdots=\left<f+a_0,f-a_0\right>,$$
which seems a bit odd. Is there any intuition behind this result? Or should I simply continue and not pay much attention to this detail?

Comment: The intuition is the same as in the least squares or linear regression. By linearity of the inner product, $2\langle a_{0},f-a_{0}\rangle=0$. That is, $f-a_0$ is perpendicular to $a_0$. This is a consequence of $f-a_0$ being the shortest vector from $f$ to the space of constants.